# How to find the $A_i$ in the matrix product state representation?

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix, tensor-networks

From what I understand, MPS is just a simpler way to write out a state, compared to the density matrix. But how do I get those $A_i$ matrices? From all the examples I read, people just somehow "have" the matrices in their pocket already. Is there a way to generate them from some random state, say $|\Psi\rangle = \alpha|\uparrow\rangle^{\otimes N}+\beta|\downarrow\rangle^{\otimes N}$, or some random density matrix? Feel free to set $N$ to small numbers if it becomes too complicated, I just really want to see an example of how this works in general, not just a GHZ state! Thanks a lot!

Crosspost with: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/638206/how-to-translate-from-a-state-density-matrix-formalism-to-matrix-product-state-r

Comment: The two best sources of information I could find were : [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product_state) and [this arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0608197)

Comment: Well, I read both of them. The Wikipedia page is exactly the one without any derivation for $A_i$, and the paper doesn't really have any kind of example.

Comment: I couldn't find anything either, it only says that schmidt decomposition is required, when someone aswers, we should update the wikipedia page !

Comment: The explanation in Vidal's paper is much more explicit https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301063

Comment: See this answer from physics StackExchange: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/565749/252841

Comment: Please mark cross-posts as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any state can be written as a matrix product state. There are systematic procedures to construct such a description, based on sequential SVDs, see e.g. Section 4.1.3 of [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477).

On the other hand, this description is usually of interest if the resulting MPS description has much less parameters than the $2^N$ parameters needed to describe a general quantum state. This is, e.g., the case for the example you give.